Is there a rule-of-thumb for when caching calculations is better than recalculating them?
I have an application in which I calculate some thermodynamic properties at various pressures and temperatures.  The nature of each calculation means that sometimes the properties are calculated at the same (Pressure & Temperature) combination several times.
As one example, a calculation at a given pressure and temperature has 28 multiplications, 7 divisions, a square-root, a square, an exponent, 11 additions and a couple of subtractions.
To try an optimise it, I was thinking that I could calculate the values at a given temperature<=>Pressure combination, and store them in an dictionary.  When the calculation was called again, it would check the dictionary to see if the same Pressure<=>Temperature combination had already been calculated, and retrieve it if it had.
To check performance, I initially set up an iteration to perform this calculation ~25,000,000 times without any dictionary, and it averaged around 6.1s across 10 runs.
I then modified the code to include caching:  If caching is turned-on, then the calculated results are stored in a dictionary, indexed by Pressure & Temperature (these are stored in a "Conditions" structure that implements IEquatable).
I found that using this caching roughly halved the time taken.
However, I thought that this was not a good "real world" example: We don't calculate 25,000,000 times at the same conditions.  So I modified it to something a bit more realistic, in that I used the same total number of iterations (25,000,000), but using 100 different temperatures.  What surprised me was that this had negligible effect on the time difference: Caching was still much faster. I then changed it to use 1,000 different temperatures, and this was faster (but not significantly).  Changing to 10,000 different temperatures was about 10% slower, but still much faster than not caching it.  I carried it on to 100,000 different temperatures (which is not a realistic scenario)



Scenario
Time




No Cache
6,180 ms


Cached, constant temperature
3,255 ms


Cached, 100 temperatures
3,203 ms


Cached, 1,000 temperatures
3,189 ms


Cached, 10,000 temperatures
3,416 ms


Cached, 100,000 temperatures
3,743 ms



It seems to me that in my particular case, caching is always worthwhile.  However, I expect that were my calculations less computationally heavy, it may not be.
So I decided to test that.  I used the 100,000 line, and tried different calculation sets:
Calculation routine:  multiplying two doubles, 10 multiplications per iteration



Scenario
Time




No Cache
1,514 ms


Cached, 100,000 temperatures
3,646 ms



I found that multiplication, division, addition and subtraction were all about the same.
Calculation routine:  One double to the Power of another (Math.Pow()) two doubles, 10 times per iteration



Scenario
Time




No Cache
7,150 ms


Cached, 100,000 temperatures
3,780 ms



Calculation routine:  (Math.Exp(double)), 10 times per iteration



Scenario
Time




No Cache
5,535 ms


Cached, 100,000 temperatures
3,766 ms



Calculation routine:  (Math.Sqrt(double)), 10 times per iteration



Scenario
Time




No Cache
1,378 ms


Cached, 100,000 temperatures
3,673 ms



For me, this was a bit of a fun exercise, but it got me wondering whether there is an analytic rule-of-thumb as to when to use caching or not.
I have read various Stack Overflow threads on efficiencies of dictionaries, and I understand that the lookup speed is not strongly affected by the size of the dictionary, which my results tend to support.  I have also read that functions like Math.Pow() are quite slow, but I don't really have a feel for how other floating point operations compare to dictionary lookups (and the additional overhead of running the calculations, ContainsKey() checks etc).
My analysis is kind-of useful, in that it shows me that the answer depends on what operations you are calculating, and how many of them.  It also points towards knowing how many times your function is likely to be called at each temperature<=>pressure combination.  But it's nothing definite.
So I thought I'd ask: Is there a rule-of-thumb, something like:
if [Number of */+- operations] + [number of Pow() operations] + [number of Exp] operations per cycle < [Y * number of expected cycles], then cache.  Otherwise don't.
Or is the best solution simply to benchmark in each section of my code using real-world computational inputs?

The cost of caching is memory. So, the question is, which is more important, memory or processing time? If process time is too expensive, but memory is limited, you could include a marker for "most used" entries (such as use count or last-used-time) that you can incorporate with a garbage collector to limit the memory use of the dictionary. Another method is to use the dictionary as a list for interpolating, reducing the total number of expensive calculations needed to form the dictionary, while also reducing the total memory requirements of the dictionary.

I think the underlying rule is "minimize (the number of) allocations"; i.e. object instances beyond simple computed values that may be created in each iteration.

there is no such rule, any optimization judged only by benchmarks, use real data for benchmark, ie log what temps/pressures are actually calculated during runtime without cache and then calculate cache hit/miss ratio and total runtime of non cached and cached version

Caching often has costs in terms of looking things up, and often wrecks locality of reference. Now, if the calculation is expensive enough (e.g. involves a network hop, or very slow, or generates a lot of "garbage") then it is still generally worth it. But for maths, which are CPUs are insanely good at? Often not.

There are tables for instruction latencies and throughput, you can also calculate or lookup the memory latency and bandwidth to make an educated guess about the performance of some calculation versus doing a memory lookup. From Latency numbers every programmer should know:
Latency Comparison Numbers (~2012)
----------------------------------
L1 cache reference                           0.5 ns
Branch mispredict                            5   ns
L2 cache reference                           7   ns                      14x L1 cache
Mutex lock/unlock                           25   ns
Main memory reference                      100   ns                      20x L2 cache, 200x L1 cache

Note that these are from 2012, but latencies tend to improve more slowly, so may still be useful to compare the relative numbers. A "cycle" is typically about 0.2ns to 0.5ns, but there is no simple relationship between cycles and executed instructions, "simple" instructions can have a throughput of more than one per cycle, and "complex" instructions may have significantly less than that.
But doing all of these calculations is likely more work than just running some benchmarks. A profiler can also be very handy to identify potential bottlenecks to focus your effort in the right places. If you really want to optimize there are also tools like intel vtune that provide more detailed profiling data than the typical .Net profiling tools.
Keep in mind that a simple loop may not be representative of real world usage. In your actual program you may have other memory traffic that compete for cache and other resources, and that may affect the results. Also keep in mind that using a dictionary makes multi threading more difficult, there is an concurrentDictionary, but that might not be quite as fast as the regular one.
